# Text formatting/word wrapping in VB .NET TabPages

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm looking at some VB .NET code that takes user input for a name, and then dynamically creates a new TabPage within a TabControl.  There's very little code - from what I can see, the relevant bit is just:

```
tp.Text = strTabName
tp.Tag = Format(asIconTabNames.Count)
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp)
asIconTabNames.Add(tp.Text)
```

strTabName is just the text it reads in from the user.  This all works fine, and sizes the tab appropriately for the text entered.  Except when it doesn't.  :-)  With certain strings (alphanumeric, etc... doesn't seem to matter) it will just randomly decide to occasionally wrap the text onto a second line.  I say randomly because there will be some names that wrap that are shorter than some that don't, and vice versa.  Obviously it's wrapping on a space, but there are longer ones also with spaces throughout that don't wrap.

I haven't been able to find any sort of pattern to it, and I haven't been able to find a property that sets wrapping to on or off.  In fact, I've found a lot of people saying that they're *trying* to word wrap within a tab and can't figure out how to, with is of course the opposite issue of what I'm seeing.

Anyone have any clues that might point me in the right direction for a setting or other explanation?  This one's got me stumped...  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to post repro code, what you've posted is not sufficient.  Be explicit about sizes, fonts and the string.

Comment: This honestly seems to be the only code outside of the designer - it just looks like everything else is set in the properties.  Font is Arial 8.25.  I can post some example strings tomorrow...

Comment: Specifically you need to post which strings cause the wrap and which don't.  also the code from the designer for the tabpage or the code where you initialize the tabpage your adding.  Hard to see if there's is a pattern, without seeing what properties have been changed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is the code that initializes the tabpage I'm adding.  (I didn't write any of this, obviously, and the person who did isn't available.)  That's literally the entire code to add one.  These are all dynamic tabpages, so they're not in the designer - only the tabcontrol is.  As for strings, "2013 GR With TEST" wraps, but "2013 GR with added test length" does not, despite being longer.